# А как сделать что бы команда написанная пользователем после выполнения удалялась?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

```
async def say(ctx, *arg):
await ctx.send(' '.join(arg))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты имеешь в виду терминал, то используй библиотеку os. Она позволяет выполнять команды в терминале из Python скрипта.

```
    import os
    os.system("cls") # Для Windows
    ####
    os.system("clear") # Для unix систем
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я всё понял!